# Installing wayfire-plugins-extra from github on Raspian "Bookworm"

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, meson-build

I'm a total beginner with Linux. I have a RaspberryPi 4 running with Raspian "Bookworm" that I want to configure to show some website in kiosk mode. Right now I'm trying to hide the cursor and apparently I need "wayfire-plugins-extra" installed.

The files and instructions may be found here: https://github.com/seffs/wayfire-plugins-extra-raspbian

Instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/seffs/wayfire-plugins-extra-raspbian && cd wayfire- plugins-extra-raspbian
meson build --prefix=/usr --buildtype=release
ninja -C build && sudo ninja -C build install
```

I get the following output when running the second line:

```
The Meson build systemVersion: 1.0.1
Source dir: /home/admin/wayfire-plugins-extra-raspbian
Build dir: /home/admin/wayfire-plugins-extra-raspbian/build
Build type: native build
Project name: wayfire-plugins-extra
Project version: 0.7.5
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 12.2.0 "cc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.40
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 12.2.0 "c++ (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.40
Host machine cpu family: aarch64
Host machine cpu: aarch64
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (1.8.1)
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.25.1)
Run-time dependency wayfire found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

meson.build:16:0: ERROR: Dependency "wayfire" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

After doing some research I found that pkg-config apparently is looking for the wayfire.pc file at the wrong location so I need to change that. But I neither know how nor what I should change it to. (Found here: https://github.com/WayfireWM/wayfire/issues/2122)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I needed to install the "wayfire-dev" package (and additionally "libglibmm-2.4-dev" package) so the dependencies were OK.